# Git Clone to Google Drive (googledrivesync)

Tags: github, google-drive-api

On my computer (Win7) I have a local install of Google drive via the googledrivesync application and the GitHub windows client. Ideally, I'd be able to use the GitHub client to clone a repository to the local Google Drive folder, then use Drive to keep edits synced up between my various devices.

The problem is that the cloned repos don't get synced up (gds says they're synced, but they don't appear on the website) and when I reboot my computer all of the cloned files are gone.

I've tried using just GitHub, and just Drive, and found both unsatisfactory. After hours of Googling I can't find anyone else having the same problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're kinda defeating the purpose of Git here. Why don't you just use git to keep your edits synced across devices?

Comment: Because I spend a lot of time on various Chromebooks, so no git. And education restrictions mean no adding Linux, either. If I just have to carry two laptops, I guess I can accept that. But it'd be great if I could get this workflow working. When I tried using Drive exclusively, it was great, but it can't compare to git for sheer utility.

Answer (score 0):

I used to, clone gdrive from https://talusoft.com/products/clonegdrive  to clone all my files. Cloned my files (670GB) including google docs to my local harddrive